# How to add code snippets in Android Studio IDE?

Tags: android, android-studio

does anyone know how to add code snippets in Android Studio IDE?
I didn't found a menu entry or something like this.

I also want to know is it possible to change the existing snippets?

Comment: You can see Complete Answer in [This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197527/is-there-a-way-to-auto-fill-arguments-names/43198778#43198778) GoodLuck

Answer (score 117, accepted):

To add/edit templates:

On the menu choose `File -> Settings`, then under `IDE Settings` (or `Editor`) go to `Live Templates`.

To insert a template:

On the menu choose `Code -> Insert Live Template` (or use it's assigned shortcut key).

**Screenshot Android Studio 3.4**
[image: Add Live Templete Android Studio 3.4]

Comment: This is now through Android Studio, Preferences (not file settings) Shortcut Key is Command J on the Mac

Comment: Highlight a piece of code -> Select Tools Menu -> Save as Live Template

Comment: Ctrl-J is the shortcut on Windows.

Comment: I have xml of live template . But how to import that file into windows 7. Please suggest for it.  I find solution for it but still not get any solution .

Comment: Live Templates is in File > Settings > Editor in Android Studio 1.5.1

Comment: For me it was cmd + shift + j on the Mac

Answer (score 22):

Code snippets are known as Live Templates in Android Studio

## Browse the current Live Templates

Go to **File > Settings > Editor > Live Templates**. Then click on the different options to see what they do.

[image]

Here are some interesting ones:

- foreach

  ```
  for ($i$ : $data$) {
      $cursor$
  }
  ```
- Toast

  ```
  android.widget.Toast.makeText($className$.this, "$text$", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  ```
- todo

  ```
  // TODO: $date$ $todo$
  ```
- logi

  ```
  android.util.Log.i(TAG, "$METHOD_NAME$: $content$");
  ```

The words surrounded by `$` signs are places where things will be filled in automatically from the context or where the user can tab through to fill them in.

## Use a Live Template

Just type in the abbreviation and tab through anything that you need to fill in.

Example:

```
logi
```

and I'm given this

```
Log.i(TAG, "myMethodName: |");
```

with the cursor located at the position I marked with the vertical line `|`.

## Make you own Live Template

Just write the code, highlight it, and go to **Tools > Save as Live Template**.

## Further Study

- [Creating and Editing Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/creating-and-editing-live-templates.html) (IntelliJ docs)
- [Level-up with Android Studio Shortcuts and Live Templates](http://blog.stablekernel.com/level-up-with-android-studio-shortcuts-and-live-templates/)
- [Android Studio Live Templates](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/android-studio-live-templates/)

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings (**File** > **Settings**, or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) then search for "Live Templates".

A template screen will be opened. You can see here all live templates and you can also create your own custom live templates.

It is important that you choose the correct template group to define your new template (e.g. "Android").

As an example, I will define a Toast method as a live template.

You can also click "use static import as possible"  not to be handle importing stuff.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cntr + j : to insert an existant live template. 
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code style -> live Templates >> add a template with button + 
edit your template and OK :)

Answer (score 1):

Select code, then

**Code -> Save as Live Template**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

go to Settings
(**Files > Settings** (ctrl + alt + s) > **then click Editor > Live Templates** )

like this:

[image]

then **type** your abbreviation name and use your template any where

[image]

[image]