# Is there a way to auto-fill arguments names?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

When I instantiate classes (or call methods) with a large number of parameters I'm always using named arguments. But it's tiring to type each argument name every time:

```
data class User(val id: String, 
                val name: String,
                val age: Int)

val user = User(id = "1", name = "John", age = 99)
```

Can IDEA pre-fill parameters like this?

```
val user = User(
    id = ,
    name = ,
    age = 
)
```

Comment: Would be a cool feature, handy for groovy too. Something you can bring up with the existing Alt+Insert menu. Lodge a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's a great plugin for that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10942-kotlin-fill-class

It autofills the constructor with some default parameters so you can override the ones you want ;)

Comment: This is a great plugin, but it would be awesome if it put the editable boxes around the values so you could tab through them easily.

Comment: You don't need a plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68198623/8429944

Comment: How did I live without it? Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

This is the way:

1. Right click on the constructor method
2. Show Context Actions
3. Add names to call arguments
4. Profit

[image: Right click on the constructor method]

[image: Show Context Actions]

[image: Add names to call arguments]

[image: Profit]

Comment: Love it! Why it's not the right answer?! It should be

Comment: This only works if you have already added the call arguments in place. Remove "someCoolValue" and then try this. You won't see "Add names to call arguments".

Answer (score 5):

Though this is not actually generating the whole call template with all the parameter names, it might be helpful anyway.

Kotlin IDEA plugin 1.1.1 suggests the parameter names in auto completion as you start typing them. For the `User` constructor from the example, start typing:

```
val u = User(i
              ^
```

There should be a suggestion `id =`:

[image]

It is inserted if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then you can continue with the other arguments:

```
val u = User(id = "123", n
                          ^
```

Here, `name =` should appear in suggestions, and so on.

Also, the parameters info popup should help you with it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See the following requests:

- [IDEABKL-6690](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6690) Automatic code completion when choosing a signature
- [IDEABKL-5496](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5496) Auto-filling the actual Java call arguments

There is an experimental feature you can enable by adding `java.completion.argument.live.template=true` into Help | Edit Custom Properties.

Comment: The experimental feature worked quite well with Java for method calls but not for constructors. However, the OP has a Kotlin tag, and I didn't see any difference with this plugin.

Answer (score 3):

If you already added all the params values in the constructor, Android studio will help you to do that.
Just click on the Object, in your case on `User`, then click on option + enter (on mac) and you will have `add names to call arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Live template:

setting **>** Editor **>** Live Templates

choice code group and add by Green Plus **1.live Template**

now you need fill items

**Abbreviation** is name for call template code.

in template type your code like it:

```
    val user = User(
            id = $arg1$,
            name = $arg2$,
            age = $arg3$
    )
```

$arg1$ means where you can type new and jump by Tab

in code when you type Abbreviation name of your code, can selected and Code Generate there

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

Breaking news! I've just found a new plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (works in Android Studio as well) that solves the problem in question perfectly.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/20654-kotlin-auto-fill

This plugin is able to auto-fill in 3 ways:

1. Fill in only all the arguments' names as "argument1 = , argument2 = ", just like in your question
2. Fill in all arguments' names with some default values assigned
3. Fill in all arguments' names with random values assigned

There is a gif demonstration on the plugin's home page as well, check it out.

After the installation, the actions will be available under the Context Actions menu **(press Alt + Enter with the cursor in the code between the parentheses)** .

I've not found a way to keymap these actions yet though (and not even sure if there is a way currently).