# Is there a way to bulk auto-fill argument names for all function or classes?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea

It's been asked and answered how to auto fill named arguments / parameters for Kotlin i.e. [Is there a way to auto-fill arguments names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197527/is-there-a-way-to-auto-fill-arguments-names)

What I am asking here is how to do this for all classes or all in a given package?

I have many callers that need to be backfilled with names and it's not practical to edit them all by hand.

Comment: Hav you tried https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14168-kotlin-function-arguments-helper and https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10942-kotlin-fill-class ?

Comment: Yes - unfortunately these are both not bulk editors and also don't modify existing callers

Comment: Seems to be a fetaure request. Please file you use-case via YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an IntelliJ / Android Studio plugin to do this: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18248-kotlin-bulk-add-name-params