Show named arguments for the Composables
Do you know where can I enable in Android Studio a functionality that automatically adds required named parameters after selecting an appropriate constructor of the Composable function? I can't find that option in the newest Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1 version of the IDE but I'm pretty sure it was available in previous versions and I can't find how this option names.
Check the GIF below:


I couldn't find the exact solution, but this answer might help the process a bit easier. It requires plugin installation
Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55580415/12176791

I know that plugin but it doesn't do exactly what's presented on the GIF. I'm almost 100% sure that option is built in IDE but must be enabled somehow. The huge difference is that the function I'm looking for adds required named arguments only for Composable functions.
