# Is it possible to include viewBinding in every project automatically?

Tags: java, android

It's quite long to change the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

to:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityMainBinding mainBinding;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(mainBinding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

every time I create a new project or an activity. Is it possible to automate this process?

Comment: I strongly recommend calling `super.onCreate()` before `ActivityMainBinding.inflate()`. In terms of changing the templates, there has never been a documented and supported way to do that, though you should find instructions for doing it lying around.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change the template cuz I have done little research, I anyone found the solution please update me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not automate the process since we have to provide the layoutId ourself. Activity  is not gonna bind to a layout automatically. What you can do is Create a `BaseActivity` and inherit it from all your `Activites`. Below is a template with binding .

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<B extends ViewDataBinding> extends AppCompatActivity {
protected abstract int getContentViewId();
protected B binding;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, getContentViewId())

}
}

class MainActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding> {
    @Override
    public int getContentViewId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // now you can directly access binding here
    }
}
```

This is just for Binding you can Also add some reusable method in `BaseActivity` and use them in Any Activity without writing them again. and [super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671897/super-oncreatesavedinstancestate) should be first line for call .

Comment: Thank you! But what is ViewDataBinding? Is that a system class or I should create it myself? IDE just can't find it

Comment: `ViewDataBinding` is a parent class for binding classes . You can just import it . It should be there it data binding is enabled.

Comment: I don't understand, for some reason Android studio sees neither ViewDataBinding, nor DataBindingUtil. I tried to import "android.databinding.DataBindingUtil" package, but it didn't work still, in spite of layout bindings work well

Comment: rebuild the project if still does not work invalidate and restart . make sure you have data binding enabled in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 1):

No, I think it's not possible but you can make **[Live Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16857108/1318946)** to get it frequently.

Or Simple that you can make a copy of that folder as a template. Whenever you need to create a new project it will be easy to copy/paste and just change the name of the project.

Thank you.