# Compose Columns and Rows Parenthesis Autocompletion

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am using autocomplete on Android Studio for Jetpack Compose code.
For the column component, the autocomplete is giving me this code:

```
Column {
        
    }
```

However, I would like it to autocomplete with a *parenthesis pair* **`()`** like this:

```
Column() {
        
    }
```

I have checked the settings and questions around this but did not find a fix. Is there a setting to adjust this?

Comment: why you prefer the one with the parenthesis? they're unnecessary...

Comment: @Lino I find myself needing to apply a `Modifier` every now and then on Rows and Columns.

Comment: You can create custom code snippets for this requirement.

Comment: Custom code snippets reference - https://stackoverflow.com/q/16857108/9636037