# Delay execution of code in method Java

Tags: java, android, delay, java-6

I want to generate random number after every 2 seconds in my java (Android) program continuously for at least 10 minutes. But I just want to pause/delay execution of code in only one method and not the whole program.

I tried using Thread like this -

```
boolean stop = false;
int random_number = 0;

while(true){
    if(stop){  //if stop becomes true, then
        return;  //terminate the method
    }

    random_number = Math.random(); //generate random number
                                   //which is used bu some other
                                   //part of code
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);        //delay the code for 2 secs
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {  //and handle the exceptions
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work as `Thread.sleep` stop the whole program execution instead on just stopping execution of code inside method and my whole screen becomes blank.

I also tried using [`Handler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15874176/3886922) but it didn't work either as it doesn't stop execution of code in my method and instead just stack up.

This will demonstrate the working of it better -

```
while(true){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("After 2 secs"); //this gets printed
                                               //later
        }
    }, 2000);
    System.out.println("Before 2 secs"); //this gets printed first
}
```

So the code stacks up making it equivalent to using while loop and make it incredibly slow.

Also, since I'm developing app for Android, I'm running on Java SE 6, so I can't use [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29). Is there any other way in which I can accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not implementing a Timer, instead of a Thread ?

Comment: Also, if you want to use `Thread.sleep(n)`, remember to run your method in a new Thread - what you did is probably ran it in the UI thread which caused UI to freeze. Timer, as suggested by @Stultuske is a good idea, though.

Comment: Ok. Let me try. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1685095 The use of threads propertly, is not basics. Hes here to learn.

Comment: Yeah, well, that's your imho. I don't think so. You should know about threads if you're doing programming. And this is the basics of using threads. The problems of concurrency is probably not the basics, imho. And yes, if he is just learning, then it's completely okay. While I would suggest learning plain java in full computer, not the mobile device, because it's easy that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:** Using threads, you might run your job off the main (UI) thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  // some code here ...

  // This might be in a loop.
  try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
  } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    // Handle ...
  }
 }
}).start();
```

Then, if this new thread you'd like to modify UI (i.e. show/hide button, display something on the screen etc), remember to pass that through the UI thread, as only this one can modify the UI. You might consider using [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) for that.

**Option 2:** Another, more Android-style way of approaching that issue is to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It contains three callbacks which can be used to do work on- and off- the UI thread. Sketch of such a code could look like:

```
 private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {
     // This method is running off the UI thread.
     // Safe to stop execution here.

     return null;
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
     // This methid is running on the UI thread. 
     // Do not stop thread here, but safe to modify the UI.
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     // Also on UI thread, executed once doInBackground()
     // finishes.
   }
 }
```

**Option 3:** Then there is also a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), as suggested by @Stultuske. It's less flexible then `AsyncTask`, but handles the interval for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
private Timer timer;
timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Generate number
            }
        }, 2000, 2000);

//Documentation (From SDK)
/**
             * Schedule a task for repeated fixed-rate execution after a specific delay
             * has passed.
             *
             * @param task
             *            the task to schedule.
             * @param delay
             *            amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
             * @param period
             *            amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent    executions.
    public void scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) {
                if (delay < 0 || period <= 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
                scheduleImpl(task, delay, period, true);
    }
```

and when you want to stop it

```
timer.cancel()
```

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your needs, you can still accomplish what you seek with Handler.

You don't have to create/start the Handler in a while loop(which, as you noticed, just stacks up unless you stop the loop itself, but it is a nonsense).

Just create the Handler and tell him to post delayed your Runnable instance. In the Runnable at the very end you check your conditions. If it is still OK, then post another runnable delayed, else you do nothing and the Handler will have no more executions.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("After 2 secs");
        random_number = Math.random();

        if (!stop) // should not be stopped, so we add another runnable;
        {
          handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        }
   }

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 2000);
```

The only downside is that Handler could freeze if the device is not used for a while, meaning it will start the counting back from where it left once the device screen is turned on.

It could do like 1 minute of correct work, then block at 1.4 seconds when the device is gone in sleep mode, and once it is turned on again, Handler would do the remaining 0.6 seconds.

Still, not knowing your needs you may be unaffected by this behavior and the answer may fit you.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use thread, do it like this :

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
      while(true){
         if(stop) break;
         random_number = Math.random();
         sleep(2000);
      }
    }
};
t.start();
```

Comment: what is `stop` . Plus should you not stop the while loop, rather than keep breaking for eternity.

Comment: variable. it has boolean atribut. look at the question

Comment: Ah yes, missed that. It should definately be `while(!stop)`. the rest is wasted lines. You've also changed his `return` - the desire to stop the thread, into `break` which would just keep it looping idly.