# How to delay seconds in android?

Tags: android, delay, system-clock

I want to delay seconds and show Toast,I try to `SystemClock.sleep`

But it only show last message("10s")...

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"1s", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
SystemClock.sleep(5000);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"5s", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
SystemClock.sleep(5000);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"10s", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

That should be displayed in sequence 1s, 5s, 10s is not it?

I also made reference to this practice, but it can not be achieved...
[How to set delay in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874117/how-to-set-delay-in-android)

So does the problem lie?

Comment: Did you try ```Thread.sleep(5000)``` ?

Comment: The second parameter is not to define the time interval. But is to define the message to be shown using Toast.

Comment: It's a better idea to use `handler` and `postDelayed` than `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this way, but the result is the same.

Comment: `handler`and`postDelayed`seem first delay and the run?

Comment: Doesn't matter what's displayed as you are FREEZING THE UI THREAD. Absolutely, completely, not at all what you want to do... ever. Most likely, the user will get the "app not responding" message. Regardless, the reason it only *seems* to show the caption is because you set the first one and then STOP THE APP... so it can't update the screen until those silly delays are over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Handler

```
public void showToast(final String message, int timeInMilliSeconds, final Context context) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, timeInMilliSeconds);
}
```

Usage:

```
showToast("1s, 1000, this);
showToast("5s, 5000, this);
showToast("10s, 10000, this);
```