# How can i call a method (loop)everytime after specific time always in android

Tags: android, multithreading

i want to call a method after every 5 seconds but it runs only one time when app starts

```
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Handler delayhandler = new Handler();
     Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loop();

        }
    };
    delayhandler.postDelayed(run, 5000);
     }

   void loop(){

  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ooh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: You can use Alarm manager for that

Comment: add the line of code of handler.postDelayed in method to be looped, keep the rest of the code as it is, it'l run automatiically

Comment: @user2450263 did ur mean to say public void run(){delayhandler.postDelayed(run, 5000);
}

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874117/how-to-set-delay-in-android

Comment: @JigneshMavani the code in the ur given link also call a method only once not every 5 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Handler delayhandler = new Handler();
     Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loop();

        }
    };
    delayhandler.postDelayed(run, 5000);
     }

   void loop(){
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ooh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
delayhandler.postDelayed(run, 5000);
  }
```

Comment: you are welcome, glad to help. Do accept the answer, makes it one less question in unanswered list :) . While you code, pls consider doing only as much/what is absolutely necessary and keeping it simple, all the best

Answer (score 1):

create method :

```
public void setAlarm(Context context, int interva) {
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interva, pi); 
}
```

then create class NotificationAlarm

```
public class NotificationAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        loop();
    }

    private void loop() {
    //work
    }
}
```

add the class in AndroidManifest

```
<receiver android:name=".NotificationAlarm" />
```

call the method in activity or service

```
setAlarm(this,5000);
```

for cancelAlarm try this:

```
public void cancelAlarm(Context context) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) G.context.getSystemService(G.context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: even if it would(assuming corrected, working) do what is asked of but that is too much unnecessary work, not needed dependency and inefficient use of broadcast receivers and alarm managers, to achieve what is necessary. Not Recommended..  
just saying so you would be aware about it

Comment: setAlarm(this,5000);  5000=Interval

Comment: I do not understand,Would you explain more?

Comment: @MikeM. thanks.. for the ack and "huge overkill", i tried thinking about terms but couldn't come up with that

Answer (score 0):

you can use Timer task for that as well like this ,

```
private Timer timer;
private TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        final Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.nextInt(2 - 0 + 1) + 0;
        random_note.setImageResource(image[i]);
    }
};

public void start() {
    if(timer != null) {
        return;
    }
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 2000);
}

public void stop() {
    timer.cancel();
    timer = null;
}
```