# Handler.postDelayed(Runnable) vs CountdownTimer

Tags: android, performance, countdowntimer, android-handler

Sometimes we need to delay a code before it runs.

This is doable by the `Handler.postDelayed(Runnable)` or `CountdownTimer`.

> Which one is better in terms of performance?

See the sample code below

**Handler**

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }, 1000);
```

**CountDownTimer**

```
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                 //DO SOMETHING
            }
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Handler` should offer you better performances as `CountDownTimer` contains itself a `Handler` as you can see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java?av=f).

Answer (score 8):

I agree that Handler is offering a better performance. But on a side note, you should keep in mind that CountDownTimer object will be destroyed after completed. A Handler will continue to exist after finished. If you only need a temporary timer then CountDownTimer is preferable. Otherwise, use a Handler.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is the only that explains that "why". Besides, all the links provided in the other answers, no longer lead to a functioning web page.

Answer (score 1):

Use Handler,Android Handler is Good.

[See Here, What Others say About Handler](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/)