# Delay For CountDown Timer - Android

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer, android-timer

I am making a chess clock but in it I need a delay (Like it waits 10 seconds before counting). I used a Handler for it but if the button is clicked in the 10 seconds, nothing happens. Please help! Thanks!
My code:

```
    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            // count down timer start
                            timer2 = new CountDownTimer(totalSeconds, Integer.parseInt(delay.getText().toString())) {
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    secondsTimer = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                                    minutesTimer = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                                    hoursTimer = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                                    person2.setText(hoursTimer + ":" + minutesTimer + ":" + secondsTimer);
                                }

                                public void onFinish() {
                                    person2.setText("Time Up!");
                                    person2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                                    mp.start();
                                }
                            }.start();
                        }
                    }, finalDelay);
```

I want a delay but I don't want to lock the UI and make the app unresponsive as it is doing right now with the handler. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you shouldn't put CountdownTimer into Handler. You could create 2 handler instead. Here is an example.

```
private void startHandlerAndWait10Seconds(){
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // Start Countdown timer after wait for 10 seconds
            startCountDown();

        }
    }, 10000);
}

private void startCountDown {
    final Handler handler2 = new Handler();
    handler2.post(new Runnable() {
        int seconds = 60;

        public void run() {
            seconds--;
            mhello.setText("" + seconds);
            if (seconds < 0) {
                // DO SOMETHING WHEN TIMES UP
                stopTimer = true;
            }
            if(stopTimer == false) {
                handler2.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer looks helpful but could you explain what is happening in the method `startHandlerAfterWaited10Seconds()` I have upvoted your answer though for finding it useful!

Comment: Hi Kharbanda,

The method you mentioned acting like countdown timer. And the reason why I suggest you using Handler instead of CountDown timer class is:
- Handler should have better performance than CountDown timer class. You could find useful refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497844/handler-postdelayedrunnable-vs-countdowntimer

Also, CounDown timer actually implemented Handler in its core.

Comment: Ok Thanks! I found your explanation useful as well as the website! Thanks a lot. But just to make sure, the countdown timer is the method `startHandlerAndWait10Seconds()` right?

Comment: Hey Kharbanda, startHandlerAndWait10Seconds() using to wait 10 seconds before start the countdown timer, startHandlerAfterWaited10Seconds() is countdown timer. I will rename to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start the timer immediately,

```
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // count down timer start
                    new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            button.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            button.setText("Time Up!");
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

And if you want to execute it after a certain time period, then

```
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // count down timer start
                    new CountDownTimer(100000, 1000) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            button.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            button.setText("Time Up!");
                        }
                    }.start();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I do want a delay but I just don't want to lock the UI and make the app unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid using `Handler` starting timer immediately

```
   private fun start10SecondsDelayTimer() {
    var delayCount = 10
    val timer = object : CountDownTimer(1_000_000L, 1000L) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            if (delayCount > 0) {
                delayCount--
            } else {
                //your calculations
            }
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            //some calculations
        }
    }
    timer.start()
}
```

but first ticks will be without your calculations