# introducing delay correctly in android/java

Tags: java, android

I want to set a booleanVariable in my project using delay.
So basically I have a boolean variable which is set to true when user touches a button. And after two seconds that boolean variable should be set back to false.
So my question is how do I introduce that delay of 2 seconds?

I have following code which DID NOT work-

```
boolean userTouch;

public void buttonTouched(){//This gets called when user touches the button
  setUserTouch(true);
  try{
  Thread.sleep(2000);
     }catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace;
     }
  setUserTouch(false);
}
```

In another method I call `getUserTouch()` method to see if user has touched the button in past 2 seconds. But that method is always set to false. It's never true.
Is there something wrong with my code? should the `setUserTouch(true);` method be inside the try block?
Also is there any other wayI can accomplish my goal? i.e. any other method by which I can introduce 2 second delay. I'm trying out countdown timer now. But I don't know any other method.

Comment: Possible Duplicate Question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15874176/6142219

Comment: Hi Deepak kaku, Handler did not work for me. I don't know which to import. There were multiple options. I tried all and notone of them worked. I also tried import android.os.*. That too did not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: use the Handler code inside buttonTouched() method. and import android.os.Handler;

Comment: Hey, I tried  `import android.os.Handler; `. That's not working. The Handler remains red and when I hover over it, android studio say can't resolve the symbol 'handler'. I also cleaned the project and rebuild it. But still same error when trying to add the imports. Android studio suggests a lot of imports for Handler like java.util.logging. But they don't work out

Comment: that is not possible. Handler is integral part of Android SDK. I don't see why you would have issues importing it. try restarting your android studio. android.os.Handler is the one you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Async task manager. You can use thread.sleep command in doInBackGround method of AsyncTask and then use publishProgress method to set the `userTouched` boolean variable back to false.

Also try following code.

```
setUserTouched(true);
long DELAY = 2000;

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code in here will get executed after DELAY variable
        setUserTouched(false);
    }
}, DELAY);
```

Comment: Hi hyper, this is actually not working for me. Because I don't know  which handler to import. There are multiple choices and none of them worked out for me. any other ideas?