# countDownTImer dont start, even another code bellow that code was executed

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I want start my count down timer after I click start button. I think, I put the syntax in a wrong structural.

Here the code:

[image]

Comment: Put you whole`CountDownTimer` code in you button's `onClick`.

Comment: Probably it is going in the wrong condition, debug by printing log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [introducing delay correctly in android/java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010965/introducing-delay-correctly-in-android-java)

Answer (score 2):

Try this on button click

```
      button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    mTextField.setText("done!");
                }

            }.start();
        }
    });
```