# How to add delay in android app while reading data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I hope all of you would be fine and doing good. I have bunch of sensors data in firebase database and i want to read specific data in my app. Like read data after 2 minutes or some specific time. Can anyone please help me out ???
i am new to android app development so detailed answers are welcome...

Comment: Have you tried looking into AlarmManager or Hanlder thread

Comment: Use handler with delay.

Answer (score 0):

**yes, you can achieve using below code.**

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // call function
            }
        },1 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new WorkManager library from Android JetPack. 
You will need to:

- Create `Worker` by extending `androidx.work.Worker` which will read data from firebase database.
- Create a `OneTimeWorkRequest` with an initial delay of two seconds and launch your worker.

You can also schedule `Work` periodically. Refer to [WorkManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Answer (score 0):

Show Process dialog until you got response from Firebase Listener.

or

You should use Progress Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler` rather than `Thread.sleep()`.

This might be helpful : [Set delay in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15874176/5584127)