# Why is the button alpha updated after the sleep

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set the StartButton alpha to 0 before the delay, for some reason is goes invisible after the sleep.

```
private void playNextGame(){
    Log.i("Info", "Start button tapped");
    StartButton.setAlpha(0);
    StartButton.setClickable(false);

    Long delay = Math.round((Math.random()*((7000-3000)+1))+3000);

    try {

        sleep(1000);

    }catch (InterruptedException e){

        Log.w("warning", e);

    }


    FirstButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    SecondButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    FirstButton.setClickable(true);
    SecondButton.setClickable(true);
}
```

Can someone help me to get the StartButton alpha to 0 before the sleep function is called?

Comment: You're sleeping the main thread which is responsible for updating the GUI.

Comment: I was also suspecting that, do you know how to only sleep this playNextGame function?

Comment: You can use a Handler postdelayed to run something after selected time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set delay in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874117/how-to-set-delay-in-android)

Comment: Thanks very much, postdelayed did the trick here.