# Android camera2 app: "app passed NULL surface"

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm trying to write my own camera app using the newer camera2 API.
At this point I'm just trying to get the app to start with the camera showing up on a fixed 640x480 SurfaceView in the emulated Nexus 5.

Here's the error I'm getting from Logcat, as well as the relevant code:
http://pastebin.com/sESf6C1p

I honestly have no clue what's wrong here, even after lots of debugging and reading the API documentation over and over. I've found some evidence that I should add a delay before calling createCaptureSession ([Android Camera - app passed NULL surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098298/android-camera-app-passed-null-surface)) which I tried with SystemClock.sleep(1000), but to no avail. Not sure what to make of "eglCreateContext: EGL error: 0x3005" either.

I'm calling createCaptureSession in the surfaceChanged callback which is run after surfaceCreated, so the surface should be all set up shouldn't it? I don't understand why the SDK is passing around a null surface internally.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: "app passed NULL surface" is a debug-level message.  The failure is an IllegalStateException from `android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.configureEGLContext`, which seems to be having trouble with the EGL context.  Are you running with GPU emulation enabled?  Have you tried your app on a real device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the error is because the emulated Nexus 5 doesn't have GL support. It worked fine on my Nexus 9 (the debug log printed "Camera configured!").

The emulator doesn't start for me without the "Use Host GPU" setting enabled, but that's a different story. I'll just run on real hardware.